# API respone cache in js

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, I want to know if there is an elegant way to cache the result of a api call, for example, we may want to get a list of items (assuming the item list will not change given the same query parameters)

```
function getItemList(query: {itemType: string; region: string | undefined; ... /* Many other query parameters */}) {
    // api call
    return client.get('/path/to/api', query)
}
```

A very simple way is encoding the query into a string and store the sting as the key of cache

```
const CACHE = {}

function getItemList(
    query: {itemType: string; region: string | undefined; ... /* Many other query parameters */}) {
    // encode
    const key = itemType + region + ...
    if (key in CACHE) return CACHE[key]
    else {
        const res = client.get('/path/to/api', query)
        CACHE[key] = res
        return res
    }
}
```

However, the encoding may have bugs. I have tried `JSON.stringfy(query)`, but the result of `stringfy` is different even for `equal` (in value) object, for example, stringfy `{itemType:1,region: 1249}` got string `'{"itemType":1,"region":1249}'` but stringfy `{region: 1249,itemType:1}` got string `'{"region":1249,"itemType":1}'`

Thanks

Comment: "*is there an elegant way to cache the result of a api call*" - yes: use the default HTTP cache that is builtin to your browser!

Answer (score 0):

Just to address the object comparisons, you can sort the object keys to have consistent object comparisons:

```js
const test = {foo: 15, bar: 'buzz'}
const target = {bar: "buzz", foo: 15}

function sortObj(obj) {
  const entries = Object.entries(obj);
  const sorted = entries.sort((a,b) => a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : 1)
  return Object.fromEntries(sorted)
}

function compare(test, target) {
  return JSON.stringify(sortObj(test)) === JSON.stringify(sortObj(target))
}

console.log(compare(test, target))
```